# "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity." Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android, floating-action-button

I'm adding a floating action button to my app, I have a material design theme and set it into the Android Manifest, I've already set the AppCompatActivity inheritance to the MainActivity but if I run my app I have an exception says " You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."

This is my main activity:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Views;

namespace M_v1
{
    [Activity(Label = "Muzzillo_v1", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar;
        private FloatingActionButton fabMain;
        private View bgFabMenu;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tablayout_navigation);

            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)FindViewById(Resource.Id.pager);
            SetupviewPager(viewPager);

            fabMain = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
            bgFabMenu = FindViewById<View>(Resource.Id.bg_fab_menu);

            fabMain.Click += FabMain_Click;

            tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

            toolbar.Title = "App_v1";
        }

        private void FabMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void SetupviewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
        {
            viewPager.OffscreenPageLimit = 2;

            PageAdapter adapter = new PageAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
            adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment1(), "One");
            adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment2(), "Two");

            viewPager.Adapter = adapter;
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my Theme:

```
<resources>
  <style  name = "AppTheme.Base" parent = "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name ="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name ="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
  </style>
</resources>
```

Android Manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Answer (score 6):

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

There are two solutions to solve your problem :

- Set `Activity` theme in Application scope in `Manifest.xml` (all activities)
- Or add a `Theme` attribute in `Activity`.

#### 1. [Theming an Application](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/material-theme/#Theming_an_Application)

Set `Activity` theme in Application scope in `Manifest.xml` (all activities) :

```
<application 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:icon="@drawable/Icon" 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</application>
```

#### 2. [Theming an Activity](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/material-theme/#Theming_an_Activity)

In Xamarin.Android, **it is recommended to add the Activity theme as an attribute**. You could read the document [Material Theme](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/material-theme/) :

> To theme an activity, you add a Theme setting to the [Activity] attribute above your activity declaration and assign Theme to the Material Theme flavor that you want to use. The following example themes an activity with Theme.Material.Light:

For example :

```
[Activity(Label = "Muzzillo_v1", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/AppTheme")]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
```